# How to set an image as background in Java application in eclipse or windows builder pro

Tags: java, image, swing, background

I was wondering how to set an image as the background to an application in Java.  I know in android it is very straight forward, and windows builder pro has a lot of amazing tools for building the Java gui so was wondering whether there was a way I could do this?  Thanks in advance!  MY application looks pretty bad as grey...

Comment: What GUI library are you currently using? Swing? Or is this still Android that you're asking about? You should add a tag for the library.

Comment: Sorry, I'm using swing components (JPanel, JFrame etc)

Comment: Then much has been written about how to make background images for Swing applications. I'm surprised that Google hasn't helped you in this.

Answer (score 2):

You can't set the background to an image exactly.  What you have to do is draw the image on the graphics during painting.  So you'll need to subclass JPanel and override the paintComponent() method, and draw the image there.

```
 public class ImagePanel extends JPanel {
     private Image bgImage;

     public Image getBackgroundImage() {
        return this.bgImage;
     }

     public void setBackgroundImage(Image image) {
        this.bgImage = image;
     }

     protected paintComponent(Graphics g) {
         super.paintComponent(g);
         g.drawImage( bgImage, 0, 0, bgImage.getWidth(null), bgImage.getHeight(null), null );
     }
 }
```

Comment: yep, this is what Google would have told him if the original poster bothered to put in the effort. 1+. Either that or use a JLabel as the contentPane after making it opaque, giving it a decent layout manager, and giving it an ImageIcon with the desired image.

Comment: Thanks for the response chubbard! Is the image in 2nd line of the paintComponent method supposed to be bgImage?  If I change it to bgImage I get a prompt saying that getWidth() and getHeight() need an ImageObserver as their arguments - what should I put there?  Also, how do I set bgImage?  Thanks

Comment: Just pass null as you expect the image to be already loaded before painting it.

Comment: A `JPanel` is an `ImageObserver` so change the last 3 instances of `null` to `this`.

Comment: Andrew is right.  I forgot JComponent is an ImageObserver.  Thanks Andrew.

Answer (score 1):

You can set your component's color by calling:

```
.setBackground(myColor);
```

Some components such as JLabels require you to call this upon it for the color change to take effect:

```
.setOpaque(true);
```

Hope this helped.

Comment: The title of his question contains the word "image", so I don't think that your answer solves his problem.

Answer (score 0):

Technically you could add a label on the whole screen and then in the icon option chane to specific background:

```
JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("n");
lblNewLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon("gene.jpg"));
lblNewLabel.setBounds(0, 0, 434, 261);
frame.getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel);
```

For example, in the Source

```
private void initialize() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

    JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Let's start!");
    btnNewButton.setFont(new Font("David", Font.ITALIC, 12));
    btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Now we will have to add some code here right =]?");
        }
    }
                                                        );
    btnNewButton.setBounds(158, 120, 89, 23);
    frame.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton);


    JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("n");
    lblNewLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon("gene.jpg"));
    lblNewLabel.setBounds(0, 0, 434, 261);
    frame.getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel);
}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JxfbF.png